# Match indexOfVisiblePointClosestToPlotAreaPoint to one axis?

Tags: macos, core-plot

I am trying to achive a mouse over high light with is common in stock charts.

Is it possible to match `indexOfVisiblePointClosestToPlotAreaPoint` to the closest point in only one axis (and not care of the other axis at all), as green line in the screendump. The point may not be the closest point if you consider both X and Y-axis (= red line), which Core Plot correctly calculates now.

Am I too tired or is there a way to only match "vertically" which point is the closest or I am going down the wrong path using `indexOfVisiblePointClosestToPlotAreaPoint` for this? ;-)

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plot data is sorted from left to right. Find the data points on either side of the green line. It's trivial to determine which one is closer to the line. A simple linear search is fine if you don't have a lot of data. Use something more efficient like a binary search if you have many data points.

Comment: Thanks Eric! I think I get the concept in general. A quick follow-up question on "Find the data points on either side of the green line" you say. How do I get the x/y-coordinates of a CorePlot data point?

Comment: You can use the plot space to convert the data values to pixel coordinates in the plot area.

Comment: [plotSpace plotAreaViewPointForPlotPoint:plotPoint numberOfCoordinates:numberCoordinates] seems to do the trick. :-)

Comment: @EricSkroch same issue but here I have two data point 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71163014/coreplot-indexofvisiblepointclosesttoplotareapoint-giving-me-wrong-index