# CorePlot "indexOfVisiblePointClosestToPlotAreaPoint" giving me wrong index

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-plot

Currently I am plotting the graph with two data plots(two lines on the graph), when I click on one line "indexOfVisiblePointClosestToPlotAreaPoint" method giving me right index and other one throwing me wrong one, not even closest visible one its skipping/jumping multiple points in between. Ex: if I click on index number 20 it jumps to 15 or 25 vice versa. Here is the calculation to find the index

```
-(NSUInteger)indexOfVisiblePointClosestToPlotAreaPoint:(CGPoint)viewPoint
{
    NSUInteger dataCount = self.cachedDataCount;
    CGPoint *viewPoints  = calloc(dataCount, sizeof(CGPoint));
    BOOL *drawPointFlags = calloc(dataCount, sizeof(BOOL));

    [self calculatePointsToDraw:drawPointFlags forPlotSpace:(CPTXYPlotSpace *)self.plotSpace includeVisiblePointsOnly:YES numberOfPoints:dataCount];
    [self calculateViewPoints:viewPoints withDrawPointFlags:drawPointFlags numberOfPoints:dataCount];

    NSInteger result = [self extremeDrawnPointIndexForFlags:drawPointFlags numberOfPoints:dataCount extremeNumIsLowerBound:YES];
    if ( result != NSNotFound ) {
        CGFloat minimumDistanceSquared = CPTNAN;
        for ( NSUInteger i = (NSUInteger)result; i < dataCount; ++i ) {
            if ( drawPointFlags[i] ) {
                CGFloat distanceSquared = squareOfDistanceBetweenPoints(viewPoint, viewPoints[i]);
                if ( isnan(minimumDistanceSquared) || (distanceSquared < minimumDistanceSquared)) {
                    minimumDistanceSquared = distanceSquared;
                    result                 = (NSInteger)i;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    free(viewPoints);
    free(drawPointFlags);

    return (NSUInteger)result;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you checking the `plot` parameter passed in the delegate method? The touch will register on the frontmost plot if there are any points within the `plotSymbolMarginForHitDetection`. It won't even check the other plot unless nothing hits on the front one. With two lines close together like that, you'll need to use a small hit margin to make sure touches register on the right plot.

Comment: how can I make sure that it hits at small margin? any particular method

Comment: Change the `plotSymbolMarginForHitDetection` property from the default to a smaller value. You might have to experiment to find a value that works for your situation that's not too finicky for the user.

Comment: Hey @EricSkroch Thanks, above suggestion worked. But how to show two different plot symbol I mean two different colours for plot symbols with respect to line colours –

Comment: Set the [`plotSymbol`](https://core-plot.github.io/iOS/interface_c_p_t_scatter_plot.html#ad7d711a385f3926dccd81cf01d0fc12e`) for each plot to different symbols. You can also use the [datasource](https://core-plot.github.io/iOS/protocol_c_p_t_scatter_plot_data_source-p.html) to provide different symbols for data points within each plot.